# A functional equation with no term outside functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functional-equations

Find all $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying
$$f(m-n+f(n))=f(m)+f(n)$$
for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}.$

I have no idea about how to find them, because there are no terms outside of the function.

Comment: $f(n)=2n$ is a solution. Not sure if it's unique, though.

Comment: @AlexR I also noted it. But it asks for all solutions.

Comment: I could find out that $f|_{f(\mathbb N)} \equiv 2n$ (i.e. restricted to it's image, $f$ must be equal to $n\mapsto 2n$. If $f(\mathbb N) = 0$, Regret's solution comes up, if $f(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$, mine comes up.

Comment: If $f(n)=0$ then $f$ must be defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: For the functional equation to hold for all $m,n$, it is necessary that $m-n+f(n)\in\mathbb N$ for all $m,n$, hence $f(n)\ge n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $n\in\mathbb N$, let $a=f(n)-n$, $b=f(n)$. Then we obtain
$$ f(m+a)=f(m)+b$$
for all $m\in\mathbb N$. Specifically, $a=0$ is only possible if $b=0$. 
By induction
$$f(m+ka)=f(m)+kb $$
Assume $f$ is not the constant zero map.
Then for suitable $n$ we have $a\ne 0$. The quotient $\frac ba$ must be the same for all such $n$ because for $a',b'$ obtained from $n'$ we have $f(m+aa')=f(m)+ab'=f(m)+a'b$.

With $m=f(n)$ we find $f(f(n))=2f(n)$, hence with $f(n)\ne 0$ for $n$ we obtain $a=f(f(n))-f(n)=f(n)$ and $b=f(f(n))=2f(n)$, so $\frac ba=2$. 
We conclude that for all $n$ with $f(n)\ne0$ we have $f(n)=2\cdot(f(n)-n)$, i.e., 
$$f(n)\in\{0,2n\}.$$
If $n,m$ are nonzero and $f(n)=2n$ and $f(m)=0$ then $$f(m+n)=f(m-n+f(n))=f(m)+f(n) =2n\notin\{0,2(m+n)\}$$
so that this constellation is not possible. We conclude that either $f(n)=2n$ for all $n$ or that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: Thanks! This part is a bit unclear to me;

Assume $f$ is not the constant zero map. Then for suitable $n$ we have a≠0. The quotient $\frac{b}{a}$ must be the same for all such n because for $a′,b′$ obtained from $n′$ we have $f(m+aa′)=f(m)+ab′=f(m)+a′b.$

Can you elaborate it a bit?

Comment: By induction he derived the equation, that he is using here. But about the non constant map comment I don't think he requires that to assume $a \neq 0$. But while defining $a$ you are assuming that $f(n) \geq n$ otherwise $a$ will spill out of the domain and thereby we will not be able to use the inductive definition of $f$ to derive the crucial identity. So I think we have to prove that $f(n) \geq n$.

Comment: He proved it above. "For the functional equation to hold for all $m,n,$ it is necessary that $m−n+f(n)∈N$ for all $m,n,$ hence $f(n)≥n.$"